# How can I remove hostname part in terminal prompt?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, prompt

My terminal prompt looks like this

```
naveen@webitmarket:~$
```

[image]

I want to remove `@webitmarket`.

How can I do that?

Comment: [Please don't post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086/22222). Just copy the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format it as code.

Comment: The picture is useful to see it's the coloured version of PS1 though...

Comment: @Zanna, in general yes I agree, but in the context/depth (no negative feelings intended) of this question I would prefer text (even unformatted is fine, edits would probably format it).

Answer (score 6):

Open a terminal <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type

```
nano .bashrc
```

press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> and type

```
PS1=
```

then <kbd>enter</kbd> - this SHOULD take you to the line you need to edit, but check as below:

Find this section of your `~/.bashrc`

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Edit the second line so it says this (remove `@\h`)

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
```

Save <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd> and exit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>, then in the terminal type

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Ma'am, I'm new in ubuntu, please tell me where it is.

Comment: @NaveenKumar I have edited, please comment if it's still not clear.

Comment: Indeed, I mistakenly typed "Enter". I removed my comment to integrate it to your answer Zanna.  Naveen Kumar. For info, the "~" sign means "home". You'll soon understand it

Comment: it is working but still same come in the title bar naveen@webitmarket

Comment: Please open a new terminal @NaveenKumar and see. If not, please paste your `~/.bashrc` file [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post a link

Comment: I wrote this command "sudo hostnamectl remove-hostname webitmarket.com" after that the settings are change

Comment: ok now I understood what you want to say and what should I do thanks sir? contact me If I deserve for helpness :-)

Comment: @NaveenKumar you fixed it yourself? Or you are still stuck? Sorry I didn't understand... :)

Comment: @NaveenKumar please ask a new question :)

Comment: ok sir and sorry :-)